# Linux found preloaded shared library: potential threat to security?

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

On a Linux Raspbian system, I have performed variuos security checks and among those I have performed a rkhunter scan to seek for rootkits, backdoors, and other malicious software with the following warning:

```
Warning: Found preloaded shared library: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-${PLATFORM}.so
```

Potentially this is a shared library providing a way to access and manage memory on the ARM platform, such as system-level memory management and may get access to critical system resources.

As far I can understand preloaded shared library pose a security risk, meaning that it has the full access to user data, system resources, and user privileges and could be potentially manipulated to gain access to secure information or resources.

I have searched for a specific documentation on such preloaded shared library, but I am not able to find any documentation about it.

I am seeking the documentation of such preloaded shared library to better understand if it poses a security issue.

I have reviewed the available posts and none answer my question.

Any support is much appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135169/what-exactly-is-libarmmem-platform-so-and-how-to-update-it It seems to be a legitimate library file for RPi systems. If you want to make sure it really is the case for your file then you could check if it is the same as in the official repositories.

Answer (score 1):

That is just a bunch of *optional* [optimized overrides for a few common string primitives](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/135169/) functions, [notably `memcmp`](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/arm-mem). The `${PLATFORM}` placeholder selects what is deemed best for your CPU.

It is not configured with ill intent, though it will introduce conflicts with some software breaking because of *how* it is configured.

If you cared enough to worry about how it may introduce security problems due to receiving limited security review and being primarily aimed at making a slow development platform go slightly less slow, you would not use that platform in the first place. Probably best to leave it in place.

If you ever wonder what package a dpkg-installed regular file belongs to, [ask `dpkg -S`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/dpkg/dpkg-query.1.en.html#COMMANDS):

> **-S, --search** *filename-search-pattern...*
>
> Search for packages that own files corresponding to the given pattern. Standard shell wildcard characters can be used in the
> pattern, where asterisk (`*`) and question mark (`?`) will match a slash,
> and backslash (`\`) will be used as an escape character.

Comment: Many thanks, do you know where can I find the documentation and the source code of it?

Comment: @LucaSpuntoni The second link leads to the source code.

Comment: Thanks again, what is not clear to me is what is the reason to implement a preloaded shared library instead of embedding the functionalities with all the rest of the distribution.

Comment: Moreover sound strange that those functionalities need to be searched inside a package named 'raspi-copies-and-fills' instead of simply 'libarmmem' in a kind of 'To look for a needle in a haystack'.